# VSCode Theme Setting: Why does the token show up white when the theme setting is black?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, vscode-extensions

I have the setting correclty set to black but the editor still shows as white? Is this a bug or do i have an invalid setting somewhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have bracket pair colorization enabled, and what colors have you set or are used default for this theme

Comment: @rioV8  TY!!! .. i didnt have a setting for it so it must be on by default... that was it `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false,` fixed it.